# CSS - Isolate elements inside div from global page styles as if it were an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sharepoint

Is it possible to isolate elements inside a div as if it were in an iFrame?

I have an app inside SharePoint that is all jacked up from the global SharePoint styles which I want to turn off completely so my app uses only the css it contains.

EG: Let's say there is a global stylesheet for the page. Let's say I put a div on that page with it's own embed css. Can I somehow ignore the global stylesheet entirely?

https://plnkr.co/edit/2H2TJJz6rNZK18OK6VLW?p=preview

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Global parent element - red</h1>

  <div class="self-contained-css">

    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {
        color:red;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>Self contained css element - blue</h1>
    <p>Self contained css should behave as if it was inside an iFrame. This is to isolate from SharePoint css ultimately.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Web Components would be your only option for encapsulation similar to an iframe. You can get pretty good coverage with a polyfill like [webcomponents.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs)

[Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) is a great framework for making Web Components easier.

This would make your code look like this:

```
... HTML here that uses your global styles ...
<my-element></my-element> <!-- this element would not inherit the global CSS -->
```

And inside of your `my-element` component (which would just be another file in your file system that you import into the page - see docs above), you can include unique styles to the content of my-element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your global styles have a !important declaration in them. While I don't normally advise this, you'd have to add it to your declaration to be able to override them. i.e.

```css
/* Global parent styles go here */

h1 {
  color:red;
  border: 5px solid red !important;
}

h1 {
        color:red;
        border: 1px solid blue !important;
      }
```

```html
<body>
  
  <h1>Global parent element - red</h1>
  
  <div class="self-contained-css">
    
    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {
        color:red;
        border: 1px solid blue !important;
      }
    </style>
    
    <h1>Self contained css element - blue</h1>
    <p>Self contained css should behave as if it was inside an iFrame. This is to isolate from SharePoint css ultimately.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I added that to simulate SharePoint global styles. I want to avoid having to hack every single element in my app because of the various global styles.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry, but it wasn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

use shadow dom in my case i use angular 1 so i used an iframe but in angular 2 we can play with shadow dom

Answer (score 0):

Use an iFrame with the srcdoc attribute set to your html.

```
var myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
myIframe.src = 'about:blank';
var info = `<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Global parent element - red</h1>

  <div class="self-contained-css">

    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {
        color:red;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>Self contained css element - blue</h1>
    <p>Self contained css should behave as if it was inside an iFrame. This is to isolate from SharePoint css ultimately.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>`;
myIframe.srcdoc = info;
var body = window.document.querySelector('body');
body.insertBefore(myIframe, body.firstChild);
```

I needed to dynamically inject my html content without being impacted by the pages css so that is why my iframe was created with js, but shouldn't be any reason that yours couldn't be written in html only. Although the srcdoc might be a little messy, so it might be cleaner to write it (the srcdoc) as a js variable and then attach it.